# Chmod doesn't work for all files

Tags: ubuntu, chmod

I'm trying to chmod my `/var/www` folder in Ubuntu, with the command: `chmod -R 775 /var/www`, and it works for the existing files. However, every time I add a new file, I have to run the command again, or else it gives me a 403 error. How can I prevent this, and chmod the directory permanently?

Comment: Check those links

http://superuser.com/questions/47463/how-to-change-permissions-on-all-files-in-a-directory-and-when-new-files-are-ad?rq=1

http://superuser.com/questions/237802/how-to-set-default-permissions-for-files-moved-or-copied-to-a-directory?rq=1

http://superuser.com/questions/503029/how-to-automatically-change-permissions-for-files-copied-to-a-directory/503192#503192